Running background task on iOS when receiving a notification
I am using react native firebase to handle notifications in my app. For android onBackgroundEventHandler works perfectly fine and is fired when a notification is received and the app is in background or killed state, but on iOS, this is never fired, infact, onMessage (which handles foreground event) is also not fired. How to register these event handlers for iOS so that we can run code in background when a notification is received.
